# How to use signals with mod_wsgi with one thread per process?

Tags: python, signals, mod-wsgi

I am trying to use a [middleware](https://github.com/zmanji/plop/blob/master/plop/wsgi.py) to profile a WSGI application. This middleware uses `plop` which is a low overhead profiler for python that relies on the `signal` module.

If I run a Django app which uses this middleware by running `./manage.py runserver --forked` then it middleware works as expected. However when the same Django app is running on apache via `mod_wsgi` then it does not work as intended.

The `mod_wsgi` instance is configured with `WSGIRestrictSignal Off` and `WSGIDaemonProcess example processes=5 threads=1` and when the Django app is run the following error occurs:

`ValueError: signal only works in main thread`

This is the same error that occurs if I run the development server without the `--forked` flag. I don't think it should be occurring with apache because the number of threads is 1.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a background thread which does a sleep() between samples should technically work and have used that approach before when have done this myself.

There is an example of creating a background thread for this purpose in:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DebuggingTechniques#Extracting_Python_Stack_Traces